# PHP (un)check a checkbox from 2 dynamic arrays while comparing them

Tags: php, sql, html, checkbox

I have 2 arrays, $item and $previousItem. $item contains all possible selections $previousItem contains selections already stored in the database. For example I have check boxes with apple, orange, banana and in my database I recorded that the user previously selected apple and banana. How can I fill the check boxes so that only orange will be unchecked while the other two will be checked. The nested for loop creates duplicates if I have more than one value for $previousItem. This must be done using only php. Is there a sort function I can use for this?

Here's the code:

```
    for($i = 0; $i < $index; $i++)
        for($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++)
    {
        echo '<li>
                <!--these are the individual check boxes-->';
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="$item+$count" value="' . $item[$j] . '"'.($previousItem[$i] == $item[$j] ?'checked': '') .'>
                <!--these are the values of the check boxes-->
                <label for="$item+$count">' . $item[$j] . '</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="item_list[]" value="' . $item[$j] . '">';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want one checkbox for each element in $item. Therefore only do one loop, over $item. It is giving duplicates because it is listing the elements in $item (the $j loop) for *every* element in $previousItem (the $i loop).

Read up on [PHP: in_array function.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) If you use that in place of `$previousItem[$i] == $item[$j]`, you can eliminate the  $previousItem loop. The syntax would be something like `in_array($item[$j],$previousItem)`